# Red dots on my new laptop?

Tags: pixels

I just purchased a new laptop with Intel HD 4400 with a dedicated NVIDIA GTX 970m graphic card. When I booted up everything was fine, but after I set up the computer I updated the NVIDIA drivers and it was one of the first things I did. Then I notice that there were two red pixels at the dark part of the screen. They are fixed in position.

Are these dead pixels? If not, what's the cause of this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick test to try to "unstick" stuck pixels: use the online [Pixel Repair](http://www.jscreenfix.com/). There's no installation, and it's a first step before trying anything more arduous.

Answer (score -1):

Connect a Display with hdmi to your laptop, If these red pixels appear on your External Display aswell it will be probably issue with the drivers, or the gpu. If not you should consider running Windows in Safe mode and see if these red pixels are still there. If they are, your screen probably have dead pixels. If they are not, we stick with the driver issue. Roll back your drivers